# Python 3 - Get n greatest elements in dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, search, hash-map

Given an dictionary with lists as values this piece of code is dedicated to find the n keys with the longest lists as values. It works, but there has to be a more elegant solution.

```
def get_n_longest_values(dictionary, n):
    result = []

    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if len(result) < n:
            result.append((key, len(value)))
        else:
            # (index, length) of smallest element
            smallest = (10e10, 10e10)
            for index in range(0, n):
                if result[index][1] < smallest[1]:
                    smallest = (index, result[index][1])

            if len(value) > smallest[1]:
                result[smallest[0]] = (key, len(value))

    return result
```

Answer (score 5):

Using the following test case, your code takes about 1 ms on my machine:

```
In [1]: import itertools
In [2]: import string

In [3]: d = dict(zip(itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=10),
             ([0] * i for i in range(1000))))
In [4]: %timeit get_n_longest_values(d, 3))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.06 ms per loop
```

First, a short style comment: In Python, `range` has an implicit `0` as its first argument, so `range(0, n)` is the same as `range(n)`.

You are doing this very manually, while it can be a bit faster when using built-in functions. I would first `sort` the items of the dictionary by the length of the values. (You cannot avoid going over the dictionary once. However this wastes some cycles, because it is a full sort, instead of a partial sort). Then you can just slice the sorted list and return the length of the values:

```
def get_n_longest_values_g(dictionary, n):
    longest_entries = sorted(
        dictionary.items(), key=lambda t: len(t[1]), reverse=True)[:n]
    return [(key, len(value)) for key, value in longest_entries]
```

This is much more readable and for the given test case performs better than your code by about a factor of 2:

```
In [5]: %timeit get_n_longest_values_g(d, 3)
1000 loops, best of 3: 514 µs per loop
```

Note that for this function, the output is actually sorted (descending), whereas yours is not.

Even for larger dictionaries, my function outperforms yours:

```
In [12]: import random
In [13]: d = dict(zip(itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=10), ([0] * random.randrange(10000) for i in range(10000))))
In [14]: %timeit get_n_longest_values(d, 3)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.2 ms per loop

In [15]: %timeit get_n_longest_values_g(d, 3)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.61 ms per loop
```

When `n` grows, your code becomes ever slower, because you iterate over the whole `result` in the worst case, whereas my code always sorts the whole dictionary anyways (same `d` as in the previous case):

```
In [18]: %timeit get_n_longest_values(d, 100)
10 loops, best of 3: 109 ms per loop

In [19]: %timeit get_n_longest_values_g(d, 100)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.27 ms per loop
```

There are a few possible routes of improvements left for this code. One could already at the beginning generate pairs of `len(values), key`, which can then be naturally sorted by Python, which should be slightly faster, as noted by @Peilonrayz in the comments. So, something like this:

```
def get_n_longest_values_g2(dictionary, n):
    return sorted([(len(value), key) for key, value in dictionary.items()],
                  reverse=True)[:n]
```

It is slightly slower than my previous function:

```
In [32]: %timeit get_n_longest_values_g2(d, 100)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.7 ms per loop
```

It has also a changed output (`len(values), key`, instead of `key, len(values)`).

Another possibility is to use your basic code and maintain a sorted `result`, so we can use binary search to insert the newest value and pop the smallest pair if needed, using the [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort):

```
import bisect


def get_n_longest_values_gb(dictionary, n):
    result = []

    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        bisect.insort(result, (len(value), key))
        if len(result) > n:
            result.pop(0)

    return result
```

This performs somewhere between the other two approaches:

```
In [42]: %timeit get_n_longest_values_gb(d, 100)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.42 ms per loop
```

Note that its output is also reversed. It is limited by `list.insert` (which `bisect.insort` calls internally) being \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ (as is `list.pop(0)`, which we could get around by using a `collections.deque`, but a `deque` also has \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ `insert`).

Lastly, one could use the [`heapq` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest), which has a `nlargest` function:

```
import heapq

def get_n_longest_values_gh(dictionary, n):
    return heapq.nlargest(n, ((len(value), key) for key, value in dictionary.items()))
```

This is the fastest for this particular test case, outperforming the `sorted` approach:

```
In [32]: %timeit get_n_longest_values_gh(d, 100)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.16 ms per loop
```

Note that its output is also reversed.

As stated in an [answer to a similar question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/151532/98493):

> The latter two functions perform best for smaller values of n. For
>   larger values, it is more efficient to use the `sorted()` function.
>   Also, when `n==1`, it is more efficient to use the built-in `min()` and
>   `max()` functions. If repeated usage of these functions is required,
>   consider turning the iterable into an actual heap.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Added `heapq`, for the fun of it. It is actually the fastest for this particular test case :)

Comment: Damn, that's cool. I can't think of any other way to do this problem with the built-in Python modules. So one of these has to be the best at some point :)